# Data dictionary linking in R

Tags: r, replace

I have two dataframes as below.

- I wanted to update the `patients` dataframe
- and swap the `Option_name` with `Option_num` for all.

```r
## dataframe
patid = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) 
technique = c("VMAT", "IMRT", "ELEC", "VMAT", "VMAT", "VMAT", "ELEC", "VMAT", "IMRT")
intent = c("Radical", "Curative", "Adjuvant", "Curative", "Curative", "Curative", "Curative", "Curative", "Adjuvant")
patients = data.frame(patid, technique, intent)
```

```r
## data dictionary
variable = c("technique", "technique", "technique", "intent", "intent", "intent")
Option_name = c("VMAT", "IMRT", "ELEC", "Radical", "Curative", "Adjuvant")
Option_num = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
dict = data.frame(variable, Option_name, Option_num)
```

So the the `patients` dataframe would change
FROM
[image: from]

TO
[image: to]

I know how to do this via a very manual process:

```r
patients$technique <- replace(as.character(patients$technique), patients$technique == "VMAT",1)
```

But I am sure there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
patients %>%
    mutate(across(c(technique, intent), 
                  ~map(as.character(.), 
                       ~dict$Option_num[which(dict$variable == cur_column() & dict$Option_name == .)])))
```

or fully `tidyverse` option:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
patients %>%
    mutate(across(c(technique, intent), 
                  ~map(as.character(.), 
                       ~pull(filter(dict, 
                                    variable == cur_column(), 
                                    Option_name == .x), 
                             Option_num))))
```

Comment: Great thanks iago! I spent all day yesterday trying to make this work and could not find a solution. I think I will go with the full tidyverse version as I am already using tidyverse and I want to try to understand this before adding another library,

Answer (score 0):

This will be for sure not the most elegant solution, but I couldn't come up with anything else.

```
for (a in c("technique", "intent")) {
  # go through the columns
  for (b in unique(patients[, a])) {
    # go through the Option_name
    patients[patients[, a] == b, a] <- dict[dict[, "variable"] == a & dict[, "Option_name"] == b, "Option_num"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ricoderks. I am getting some error messages [Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, patients[, a] == b, a, value = 2) : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
In addition: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated]

Comment: Mmmm, that's weird! I just ran the code with the data from your question and I don't get an error! It looks like you have `NA`'s in your data or some columns are factors while in your example data there is no factor. Oh something just popped my mind. I'am running R 4.0.2. If I'am correct going to R 4.x.y they changed the default for `stringAsFactors` to `FALSE`. I just tried setting `stringAsFactors = TRUE` in `data.frame` and I also get the error. Good to know! If you are already familiar with tidyverse I would go with the solution for iago.